# Generating array for grouped_options_select view helper in Rails

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Location` model with `name` and `area` attributes. I would like to create a select input field, where my options are grouped, like so:

```
<optgroup label="Area1">
   <option value=1>Location 1</option>
   <option value=2>Location 2</option>
   <option value=3>Location 3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Area2">
   <option value=4>Location 4</option>
   <option value=5>Location 5</option>
   <option value=6>Location 6</option>
</optgroup>
```

I have tried the following in my controller and view:

controller:

```
@grouped_locations = Location.pluck(:area, :name).group_by(&:first).
                  map { |k, v_ary| [k, v_ary.map(&:last)] }.
                  map { |k, v_ary| [k, v_ary.map.with_index { |v, i| [v,i+1] }] }
```

view:

```
<%= f.select :location_id grouped_options_For_select(@grouped_locations)
```

The above code gets me a select field with repeating values, like so:

```
<optgroup label="Area1">
   <option value=1>Location 1</option>
   <option value=2>Location 2</option>
   <option value=3>Location 3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Area2">
   <option value=1>Location 4</option>
   <option value=2>Location 5</option>
   <option value=3>Location 6</option>
</optgroup>
```

How do I set up the `grouped_locations` array so that the values do not repeat, as in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map.with_index` part is where the index starts from 0 for each area. So you need to keep track of the indexes:

```
i = 0

@grouped_locations = \
  Location.pluck(:area, :name).group_by(&:first).
  map{ |k, v_ary| [k, v_ary.map(&:last)] }.
  map{ |k, v_ary| [k, v_ary.map{ |v| [v, (i += 1)] }] }
```

Those last two `map` can be combined BTW into a single `map`:

```
map do |k, v_ary|
  [k, v_ary.map{ |v| [v.last, (i += 1)] }]
end
```

That should do the trick.

But I would recommend simply using IDs as values and avoid iterating over your results with multiple `map`s.

```
@grouped_locations = \
  Location.pluck(:area, :id, :name).each_with_object({}) do |location, hash|
    area, id, name = location
    (hash[area] ||= []) << [name, id]
  end.to_a # remove 'to_a' if not required by 'grouped_options_for_select'
```